# Is writing semantic html important in a electron app?

Tags: electron

I am writing a electron app. It won't have its use on the web as it operates with the file system. Is it worth writing article instead of div, using ul and overwriting their default styles and all other semantic html5 accessible features. While I understand it is good practise it will take extra time and ship size etc.. and I am not aware screen reader support in Electron.

Comment: You already answered your own question. If you believe accessibility is important for your application then do it. Otherwise don't.